# Pygame How to use walking animations

Tags: python, pygame

When I walk Up, Down, Left, or Right I want 3 images to play while I'm walking in that direction.

```
player = pygame.image.load('data/down1.png')

playerX = 610
playerY = 350

while 1:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player = pygame.image.load('data/down1.png')
                player = pygame.image.load('data/down2.png')
                player = pygame.image.load('data/down3.png')
                playerY = playerY + 5

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))

        pygame.display.flip()
```

(This is part of my code btw)
So is there a way I can make it so when I'm walking down it plays like an animation of the walking down images?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a circular buffer with the names.

```
images = ['data/down1.png','data/down2.png','data/down3.png']
```

and then change a counter

```
...

if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    player = pygame.image.load(images[counter])
    counter = (counter + 1) % len(images)
    playerY = playerY + 5
...
```

It will change the image while the button is pressed.

Comment: This is a good answer. My answer explains almost the same idea, but in a more complex way.

Comment: user3777041, please note that this is a simplification, read carefully  the "The Maniac" answer, he point's out problems you can have in the future of you design.

Comment: It would be more efficient to load the images before the main loop starts instead of loading them from the hard disk repeatedly. Also, call the [`pygame.Surface.convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha` methods.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: You've gotta do the animation yourself

All you're doing in that code is loading 3 images, with the 3rd one being shown since it was the last to overwrite the `player` variable. You'll need to set up an animation loop, which is quite complex and out of the scope of a StackExchange reply, unfortunately.

Here's the general idea though, hopefully you can find a more complete tutorial on this:

1. Create **sets** of sprites for each of the movement directions. This should be done outside of the main loop.
2. Your event handler should just handle sprite position and state (i.e. "moving up" or "moving down").
3. Inside your main loop, but outside of the event handler if-statement, check for the player's movement state. This determines the **set** of sprites you'll be using.
4. Finally, determine the "next" sprite that should be shown and display it. Note: take into account your FPS, and figure how how many frames each sprite should be shown. In your case each frame is 1/30th of a second, so maybe 5-10 frames per sprite?

This is a vast oversimplification so be ready to figure out more as you go. This is probably a very inefficient way to do it as well, but you shouldn't worry about optimization until you need to (i.e. you're game is lagging). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is more complicated then you think.

You have to load images in list (not in one variable `player`).
You need variable `walking = True`. 
If `walking == True` then display next image from list and `playerY = playerY + 1`.
On next loop do the same till player moved to expected position. Then `walking = False`.

I can check it but it will look more like this:

```
player_images = []
player_images.append( pygame.image.load('data/down1.png') )
player_images.append( pygame.image.load('data/down2.png') )
player_images.append( pygame.image.load('data/down3.png') )
player_current = 0
player = player_images[ player_current ]

playerX = 610
playerY = 350

walking = False
walking_steps = 0

while True:

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(30)

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
               return
           elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
               walking = True
               walking_steps = 5

    # --- moves ---    

    if walking == True:
        # here you need to check some counter 
        # if it is time for next step to walk slower
        # but don't use `time.sleep()`
        if walking_steps > 0:
            player_current = (player_current + 1) % len(player_images)
            player = player_images[ player_current ]
            playerY = playerY + 1
            walking_steps -= 1
        else:
            walking = False

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(player, (playerX, playerY))

    pygame.display.flip()
```